# How do I enable sound on Macbook Pro 14.1 (2017)?

Tags: sound, macbook, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Macbook Pro 14.1 (2017)?
but there is no sound. How do I enable sound?

I have tried the following commands:

```
apt install wget make gcc linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro.git
cd snd_hda_macbookpro
sudo ./install.cirrus.driver.sh
```

I have also rebooted a number of times and many more methods available on the internet

Comment: Hello. As written the question is making little or no sense. You need to add much more detail. From your question exact commands are needed. <and many more methods available on internet>

Comment: Where are you getting this information? Please link to any guides you are following. You should also include more details about everything you've tried so far.  FYI: Cloning a GitHub repo doesn't do anything except copy files from the repo to your hard drive.

Comment: This ^^^ If you did exactly as posted and nothing else then nothing was installed, nothing changed. After cloning the GitHub and cd'ing to the cloned folder you were supposed to run the script: `sudo ./install.cirrus.driver.sh` and reboot. Did you?

Comment: ChanganAuto- Yes i did "sudo ./install.cirrus.driver.sh" too and rebooted but it doesn't work